# Unescape the chinese characters in url?

Tags: python, escaping, urlencode

Sometimes, Chinese characters are escaped into forms like:

%B9%F3%D6%DD%C3%A9%CC%A8

How do I convert these back to readable chinese characters in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `urllib2.unquote` like this:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> print urllib2.unquote('%B9%F3%D6%DD%C3%A9%CC%A8').decode('gbk')
贵州茅台
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
urllib.unquote(your_string).decode(your_encoding)
```