# Translate Chinese to urlencoding in awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, url-encoding

I have a .txt file. And each line contains Chinese. I want to translate the Chinese to urlencoding.

How can I get it?

txt.file

```
http://wiki.com/    中文
http://wiki.com/    中国
```

target.file

```
http://wiki.com/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87
http://wiki.com/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD
```

I found a `shell` script way to approach it like this:

```
echo '中文' | tr -d '\n' | xxd -plain | sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
```

So, I wanna embed it in  `awk` like this, but I failed:

```
awk -F'\t' '{
    a=system("echo '"$2"'| tr -d '\n' | xxd -plain | \
    sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]");

    print $1a
}' txt.file
```

I have tried another way to write an outside function and call it in `awk`, code like this, failed it again.

```
zh2url()
{
   echo $1 | tr -d '\n' | xxd -plain | sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
}
export -f zh2url
awk -F'\t' "{a=system(\"zh2url $2\");print $1a}" txt.file
```

Please implement it with `awk` command because I actually have another thing need to handle in `awk` at the same time.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you have tried so far and provide any information you have uncovered to date on how to do the translation.

Comment: python way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736452/unescape-the-chinese-characters-in-url

Comment: @josifoski Thanks for your ans. Actually I have another things need to handle in `awk` at the same time.  So I will appreciate `awk` way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk for co-processes, etc.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function xlate(old,     cmd, new) {
    cmd = "xxd -plain"
    printf "%s", old |& cmd
    close(cmd,"to")
    if ( (cmd |& getline rslt) > 0 ) {
        new = toupper(gensub(/../,"%&","g",rslt))
    }
    close(cmd)
    return new
}
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
{ print $1 xlate($2) }

$ awk -f tst.awk txt.file
http://wiki.com/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87
http://wiki.com/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you simply explain what's the meaning of `printf "%s", old |& cmd` `close(cmd,"to")` and  `(cmd |& getline rslt) > 0` I'm confused by this magical shell!

Comment: @geekeeper the above is an awk script, not a shell script. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fCoprocess and http://awk.info/?tip/getline for the answer to that particular question and get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.